# A simple query is generating multiple nested records

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or Entity Framework is returning multiple nested results and I am not able to figure out why or how to stop it from happening.

I am trying to get a list of users for a specific role:

```
return _context.users.Include(user => user.UserRoles)
            .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).Where(ro => ro.UserRoles.Any(i => i.roleId == role.RoleId)).Take(10).ToList();
```

I have three models: User, UserRoles, Role

User has many roles through UserRoles

```
public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

UserRole belongs to User and belongs to Role

```
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }     
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

and Role

```
public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

When I query list of all the users for a given role, I am getting following type of results:

```
[
{
    name: 'xxxx', 
    email: 'xxxx', 
    userRoles: [{
        userRoleId: '',
        roleId: '',
        role: {
            roleId: '',
            name:'',
            userRoles: [
                {
                    userRoleId: '',
                    roleId: '',
                    user: {
                        and the loop continues
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    ]
}
]
```

I am expecting following results:

```
[
  {
    name: 'xxxx', 
    email: 'xxxx', 
    userRoles: [{
        userRoleId: '',
        roleId: '',
        role: {
            roleId: '',
            name:''                
        }
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: See [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization) EF Core documentation topic.

Comment: I already have this:
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> services.AddMvc()
>           .AddJsonOptions(
>               options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
>           );

This method is mainly to prevent wireless circular references , if you want to change the format of the json returned , you could try the following workaround that selects the data you want

```
var data= _context.Users
                .Include(user => user.UserRoles)
                    .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)
                    .Where(ro => ro.UserRoles.Any(i => i.RoleId == roleId))
                    .Select(u=>new {
                        name=u.UserName,
                        userRoles=u.UserRoles.Select(ur=>new {
                            roleId=ur.RoleId,
                            role=ur.Role.RoleName

                        })
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thats what I end up doing. Thanks

Comment: @AjitSingh, I'm glad that your issue was resolved . If you find that my workaround works , could you mark my reply as the answer ? Thanks a lot !